# C++ Being told that there is a missing semicolon by compiler when trying to create a for loop

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Why am I getting told that there is a missing ; when trying to create this for loop?

[image: ; error]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Replace `for( count=1, count<=100, count++)` with -

```
for( count=1; count<=100; count++)
```

**for syntax:**

for ( init-expression ; cond-expression ; loop-expression )
   statement

Comment: Wow, such a simple mistake, Thanks.

Comment: Also to note is that it can't just outright say you used comma instead of semi-colon because commas are perfectly legal in for lool declarations. For instance, if you want to initialize more than one variable, you can use commas in the init portion to do that.